# Django - Class based to Function based

Tags: python, django

I'm practicing Django. This code is from one of the tutorials. Basically right now I am practicing in function based view however the below code is in class based. How can I convert it to a function based view?

View:

```
class  MovieCategory(ListView):
    model = Movie
 
    def get_queryset(self):
       self.category= self.kwargs['category']
       movies = Movie.objects.filter(category = self.category)
       return movies

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(MovieCategory,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['movie_category'] = self.category
        return context
```

Model:

```
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
           
        ('en','ENGLISH'),
        ('gr','GERMAN'),
    
    )
    
    class Movie(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        discription = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies')
        category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES , max_length=20)
        language =  models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES , max_length=20)
```

Comment: what do you mean by ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
# view
def movie_category_list_view(request, category):
    movies = Movie.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        "movies": movies,
        "category": category
    }
    return render(request, "movies.html", context)

# urls.py
path('<str:category>/movies/', movie_category_list_view, name="moviecategory")
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done this way:

```
def movie_category_view(request):
    category = request.GET.get("category")
    if category is None:
        raise Http404("Category doesn't exist")
    movies = Movie.objects.filter(category = category)
    context = {
        "movie_category": category,
    }
    return render(request, "your/template/path", context)
```